# Simple JOLT transformation. Add one level and paste part of attributes here

Tags: json, jolt

Please, help to modify next json. I need add one level and paste part of attributes here.

Input:

```json
{
  "Name" : "Some order",
  "Status" : "New",
  "Project" : "Some project",
  "Goal" : "Some goal",
  "Urgency" : "",
  "URL" : "",
  "table_name": "Order"
}
```

Desired output:

```json
{
  "row": {
      "Name" : "Some order",
      "Status" : "New",
      "Project" : "Some project",
      "Goal" : "Some goal",
      "Urgency" : "",
      "URL" : ""
},
 "table_name": "Order"
}
```

If you have some cool sources about JOLT, please, share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "table_name": "&",
      "*": "row.&"
    }
  }
]
```

where you just need to nest the elements under `row` key other than the element with `table_name` key. `&`(`&0`) represents the nearest key(without going up any level, eg. in that case you would need to use `&1`,`&2`...etc in order to go `1`,`2`,.. levels up)

You can check [this](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) site out as a nice reference.